# Setting a contact to "deceased" cause the contact to lose its subtype

Tags: civicrm-contact

Drupal 7 with CiviCRM 5.68.

Setting a contact to "deceased" cause that the contact lose the subtype, and all the custom fields, which are visible / filled (because the contact had a subtype).

How can I prevent losing subtype?

Thnaks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Do you have any related extensions that might cause it?

Comment: I found the string, which is shown in a Javascript alert. It's in templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Contact.tpl, in line 222.

Comment: That [string](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/bb41ba8e780d584e204280f25d551a3597b7c66c/templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Contact.tpl#L222C51-L222C150) is normal when you remove a contact subtype, but setting to deceased shouldn't cause it to remove contact subtypes. Do you have any extensions installed related to subtypes or deceased?

Comment: No. I have Contact Layout Editor installed, which is somehow related with contact's data, and one trigger on ```civicrm_contact``` table, to update the ```is_deceased``` boolean, if the date of decease is in empty.

Comment: Here are my extensions: AuthX, Access Control by Financial Type for Reports, CiviCRM Export to Excel, CiviCRM Log Viewer, CiviCampaign, CiviContribute, CiviEvent, CiviMail, CiviMember, CiviPledge, CiviReport, AdminUI, CiviGrant, CKEditor4, Contribution cancel actions, Civisualize, Finsbury Park Theme, Custom search framework, Message Administration, CSV GUI Import to api, ExtendedReport, CiviRules, Form Core, FormBuilder, Contact Layout Editor, FlexMailer, SearchKit, Pivot Report, General Data Protection Regulation, Email Address Corrector

Comment: I found an extremely interesting log entry:
```[warning] Using a CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR separated subType deprecated, use a comma-separated string instead. Caller: CRM_Contact_Form_Contact::preProcess
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)```
Could this cause loosing contact's subtype?

Comment: Maybe. There was a recent update for that warning - can you try applying this patch: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28612/files